# Set product category over category_id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to find a way to set a category for a product over category_id but I don't know how could I use to id to set the category

My productDTO with just the basics:

```
public class ProductDTO {

private Integer id;





private String title;


private Category category;


private BigDecimal price;


private LocalDateTime createdAt;


private Integer category_id;
```

My product service

```
public class ProductService {

@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

@Autowired
ProductMapper productMapper;


public void addProduct(ProductDTO productDTO){
    productDTO.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());

    productDTO.setCategory(productDTO.getCategory());
    Product productEntity= productMapper.convertToEntity(productDTO);

    productRepository.save(productEntity);
}}
```

I tried doing it with this service class but it obviously couldn't work...
The error :
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `pavicevic.koArtwebshop.entity.Category` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException"

Edit:
Here is my POST method

```
 @PostMapping(value = "api/products/add")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createProduct(@RequestBody ProductDTO productDTO) {
    productService.addProduct(productDTO);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: Show us the content of the body your call to your POST or PUT method.  This looks like the error is in your controller, where it attempts to marshal the object you are passing in via the body to your model entity or bean class, and finding that the elements don't map.

Comment: No, @Howard007 means the http body, i.e. what json are you sending?  It looks like it's trying to construct an instance of `Category` from just an int, but can't figure out how to do it.  It's looking for a constructor or factory method to turn an `int` into a `Category`

Comment: The JSON that comes in as the HTTP body has to match structurally the definition of your ProductDTO class. For example if it has the fields id, name, description, then the JSON input payload should look something like { "id": 1001, "name": "ProductX", "description": "Most awesome product ever!"}

Comment: I know how to do that, but I want to be sending an id instead of the object